# Is the use of eigenvectors when representing a solution to a system of ODEs "mandatory", or just useful?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading Appendix 3 of "Practical Bifurcation and Stability Analysis" by Seydel. It is explained that, if $A$ is a square matrix of constant coefficients in the vector ODE:

$$\dot{\mathbf{y}}=A\mathbf{y} $$

Then, the structure solution is simplest when $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\mathbf{w_k}$ and $\lambda_k$; simply:

$$\mathbf{y}_k=\exp(\lambda_kt)\mathbf{w}_k$$

Now the exponential term is clear, but what confuses me a bit is the use of the eigenvector. The fact that:

$$\dot{\mathbf{y}}_k=\lambda_k\exp(\lambda_kt)\mathbf{w}_k+\exp(\lambda_kt)\dot{\mathbf{w}}_k=A\mathbf{y}_k=\lambda_k\mathbf{y}_k $$

Imply that the eigenvectors are independent of $t$ such that $\dot{\textbf{w}}_k=0$, and are simply included as they are the simplest way to write the solution, instead of, for example, using Cartesian vectors. Is this correct?

Comment: What would you propose as alternative? Note that the $w_k$ are variable within their eigenspace, so that they can be adjusted to satisfy the initial condition. Otherwise write $w_k=c_kv_k$ with $v_k$ fixed for all solutions. The initial conditions now give a linear system for the coefficients $c_k$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh, that perspective makes it very clear. Thank you.